# How can I stop a flip effect from pushing other elements away from it?

Tags: javascript, css, button, flip

I've been bashing my head against this on and off for the past two days. Essentially I have a "Contact me" card at the bottom of my page which flips when clicked to reveal a message. The problem is that no matter how much space I put it in, it always pushes the other elements away when it flips. This causes the footer to be pushed down off screen which I don't think looks great!

I've tried to add and remove margins from the button, the footer and the paragraph above the button, nothing seems to work. The closest I've got is sticking the footer to the bottom of the page but then it's there from loading which obviously doesn't work either. Any help very much appreciated!

```
        <div class="titles faded">
      <h2>My skills</h2>
      <p class = "skills-text">My strongest points are HTML and CSS, followed by Javascript. I've also got experience making React apps, creating and maintaining SQL and MongoDB databases, using API's and more. My aim is to become a solid full stack developer, I find
        both front and back end to be equally challenging, interesting and satisfying to work with.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="btn faded">
      <div class="btn-back">
        <p>If you'd like to get in touch about hiring me for a full time job or just a small project, please get in touch by my email.</a> I look forward to hearing from you!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-front">Contact me?</div>
    </div>
  </div>

      <div class="footer">
        <footer>
          <p>All content copyright Donald Barr 2021</p>
        </footer>
      </div>
```

The CSS

```
.btn {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  margin:auto;
  transition: width 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), height 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn-front {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 7px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 80px;
  background-color: #1f2839;
  color: #ACBCE8;
  cursor: pointer;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: background 0.5s ease, line-height 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}

.btn-front:hover {
  background-color: #8BA3D6;
}

.btn-back {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 7px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -500px;
  background-color: #8BA3D6;
  color: #1f2839;
  transform: translateZ(-2px) rotateX(180deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: box-shadow 0.8s ease;
}
```

Here you can see the effect of the footer being pushed away[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: Position the card to a fixed position instead of absolute.

Comment: This stops it pushing things away but makes it float at the bottom of the screen when I'm on the rest of the page. Is there a way to have it positioned off the bottom of the document instead of the bottom of the window? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved it myself if this is useful to anyone in future:

Kept the position of the button elements as absolute but added:

```
left:0;
right:0;
```

to the overall .btn element. No idea how this fixes it but it seems to. Hope this is useful to someone!